# Accessing a variable defined by a constructor function through another class

Tags: actionscript-3, class, variables, flash-cs6

I have two classes, the first one is called CoreModus. In CoreModus (which is a non-document class) I declare a "global" variable, called modus, using the constructor function `CoreModus(modus);`

CoreModus.as:

```
package myStudio.basic {
    public class CoreModus {
        public var modus:String;
        public function CoreModus(structure:String) {
            modus = structure;
        }
        public function setup():String {
            return modus;
        }
    }
}
```

The second class is called Animation, which is a non-document class, and I want to access the variable modus, which is declared in CoreModus constructor function: i.e CoreModus("non-linear"); which in this case `modus = non-linear`.

Animation.as:

```
package myStudio.basic {
    import fl.transitions.Tween
    public class Animation {
        public var anim:Tween;
        public function Animation() {}
        public function tryToRetrieveModus():void {
            var modo:CoreModus = new CoreModus();
            var modus:String = modo.getModus();
            trace("I'm trying to retrieve the modus " + modus);
        }
    }   
}
```

Of course, because CoreModus needs a parameter, I can't use the option I tried in Animation.as (making an instance of CoreModus).

FLA document, frame 1:

```
import myStudio.basic.CoreModus;
import myStudio.basic.Animation;

var modo:CoreModus = new CoreModus("non-linear");
var mov1:Animation = new Animation();

trace(modo.setup());
mov1.tryToRetrieveModus();
```

Is there any other way to access to this variable?

P.S. I omitted a bunch of unrelated lines in CoreModus(); constructor function. I don't want that code to be processed every time, for CPU's sake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the variable from your CoreModus class instance, first create the instance of the class somewhere.

Then, pass the instance reference to the the Animation class instance. After that you can use the public variable of CoreModus as you please.

Here's an example:

```
//creating the CoreModus class instance
var myCoreModus:CoreModus = new CoreModus("my string");

//creating the Animation class instance
var myAni:Animation = new Animation();
myAni.modo = myCoreModus; // make sure that modo is public instance variable
```

You can also make your CoreModus a singleton and have a static variable if you have only one instance of your CoreModus.